# Will Second Promise wait for the First Promise to complete Before it start

Tags: javascript, promise

So I am working on a project after learning promise for some time ago, I needed it in my current project, but I was bluffed by the result am getting.

I have two promises, **promise1** and **promise2**, in **promise1** I have some kind of loops and loading of data, in **promise2** I have another logic which doesn't rely on the completion of the **promise1** to execute. So, since **promise** is the best way of handling these two executions differently based on my understanding, it means that **promise1** don't have to complete before **promise2** starts, or am I wrong, because from my result, I can see that **promise1** has to complete before **promise2** starts, but every other code in the file executes without waiting for the **promises** to complete which is good.

If this is the default behavior of promise, then I will need to know how make the two promises to run asynchronously without depending on each other.

Here is my code example below

```
let promise1 = new Promise((res, rej) =>{
    for(let i = 0; i < 52435435; i++){

    }
    res('done')
});

let promise2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res('Done second')
})

promise1.then(txt => console.log(txt))
promise2.then(txt => console.log(txt))

console.log('Last console')
```

result

```
Last console
app.js:12 done
app.js:13 Done second
```

Comment: You might be after [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which allows you to run multiple async tasks concurrently?

Comment: If there is no asynchronous operation inside the `Promise`, the for loop is completed even before the second promise is defined.

Comment: You should use Promise.all() if you want your second promise to wait for first promise. In this case you'll be able to resolve both of them together. There's no other way to alter the execution of Promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read about JS workers pool.
Your for loop not give any other task chance to get some cpu.
Use setTimeout to simulate an async process!